# Arabic word search tool

Tags: vb6

I want to make a search tool to find a specific word in the Arabic language that i can find just the word for example:

ذهب الولد إلى المدرسة من البيت و منهم الى البيت

If I try to find the word "من", the code not only finds the word "من", but also finds part of the word " منهم". I don't want the program to do that. I want to find the word " من"  and every word like it and make whole case to the word.

To make things more clear (using an English example), if I were to search for the word 'to' in the following sentence, I would only want whole words to be found, and not words that contain the word 'to' such as 'toward' to become a part of the result.

Sentence: I want to go towards the bus.

Comment: I tried rewriting the question to make more sense of it. However, I got stuck on the last sentence. Can you please rewrite it explaining by what you mean by "and every word like it" and "make whole case to the word"? Also, since it sounds as if you have tried to already write code, can you please post the smallest amount of VB code that exhibits the problem, and some sample text to test it with.

Comment: before any thing,  i should say " thank you" very much for your attention and importance,
i mean by the sent.(and every word like it) that every word like "من" in the text. about the English example: "to go towards" when i search about "to" in the text it also find "towards" because the word "towards" contains "to"
about the code i used the following code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searches like this can be frustrating.  What I usually do is to add a space at the front of the search string and also at the end and then search for SearchString.

So... "I want to go towards the bus." becomes " I want to go towards the bus. ".  Then I search for " to ".  The problem with this method is that punctuation can cause a problem.  For example, if you wanted to search for "bus", you would use:

" I want to go towards the bus. " and search for " bus ".  This would not be found because there is punctuation after the word bus.

I would encourage you to use regular expressions for this functionality.  VB6 does not have regular expressions built in, but you can use the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions functionality to accomplish this.  Please take a look at this page to help you get started:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818802

**Edit based on your comment**

You have this line of code:

```
pos = InStr(start_at, txtBody.Text, target)
```

try changing that line to this:

```
pos = InStr(start_at, " " & txtBody.Text & " ", " " & target & " ", vbBinaryCompare)
```

By adding spaces in the code, you are actually checking for (space)target(space).  So that you don't miss potential matches at the beginning or end of txtBody.Text, spaces are added there (for comparison purposes only).  By adding vbBinaryCompare, InStr will now perform a case sensitive search.

Comment: thank you for your answer.. but your answer don't serve my problem.. i say again i want to find the word "to" not part of the word like "towards" ...i use the following code:  Option Explicit

Private TargetPosition As Integer
' Find the text.
Private Sub cmdFind_Click()
    FindText 1
End Sub
Private Sub FindText(ByVal start_at As Integer)
Dim pos As Integer
Dim target As String

    target = txtTarget.Text
    pos = InStr(start_at, txtBody.Text, target)
    If pos > 0 Then
        ' We found it.
        TargetPosition = pos
        txtBody.SelStart = TargetPosition - 1
        txtBody.Sel

Comment: I modified my answer so that it (hopefully) solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only completely thorough way of doing this is to use the Instr() function, and then check that the next character is a punctuation character, a newline, or the word is at the end of the string, e.g.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetStringTypeW Lib "Kernel32.dll" ( _
    ByVal dwInfoType As Long, _
    ByVal lpSrcStr As Long, _
    ByVal cchSrc As Long, _
    ByRef lpCharType As Integer _
) As Long

Private Const CT_CTYPE1                     As Long = &H1

Private Const C1_UPPER                      As Long = &H1     ' Uppercase
Private Const C1_LOWER                      As Long = &H2     ' Lowercase
Private Const C1_DIGIT                      As Long = &H4     ' Decimal digits
Private Const C1_SPACE                      As Long = &H8     ' Space characters
Private Const C1_PUNCT                      As Long = &H10    ' Punctuation
Private Const C1_CNTRL                      As Long = &H20    ' Control characters
Private Const C1_BLANK                      As Long = &H40    ' Blank characters
Private Const C1_XDIGIT                     As Long = &H80    ' Hexadecimal digits
Private Const C1_ALPHA                      As Long = &H100   ' Any linguistic character: alphabetical, syllabary, or ideographic
Private Const C1_DEFINED                    As Long = &H200   ' A defined character, but not one of the other C1_* types

Function FindFullWord(ByVal in_lStartPos As Long, ByRef in_sText As String, ByRef in_sSearch As String, Optional ByVal in_eCompareMethod As VbCompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare) As Long

    Dim nLenText    As Long
    Dim nLenSearch  As Long
    Dim sNextChar   As String
    Dim iCharType   As Integer

    FindFullWord = InStr(in_lStartPos, in_sText, in_sSearch, in_eCompareMethod)

    ' Did we find the search string in the text?
    If (FindFullWord > 0) Then

        ' Save the length of the text.
        nLenText = Len(in_sText)
        nLenSearch = Len(in_sSearch)

        Do

            ' Does this position mean that the search  is the end of the string?
            If (FindFullWord + nLenSearch - 1) = nLenText Then
                ' If so, we can exit now - there are no following characters.
                Exit Function
            End If

            ' Look at the next character.
            sNextChar = Mid$(in_sText, FindFullWord + nLenSearch, 1)

            ' Is this next char a space, punctuation character, or a blank?
            If (GetStringTypeW(CT_CTYPE1, StrPtr(sNextChar), 1, iCharType)) Then
                If (iCharType And C1_SPACE) = C1_SPACE Then
                    Exit Function
                ElseIf (iCharType And C1_PUNCT) = C1_PUNCT Then
                    Exit Function
                ElseIf (iCharType And C1_BLANK) = C1_BLANK Then
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If

            ' Find the position of the search string in the text.
            FindFullWord = InStr(FindFullWord + nLenSearch, in_sText, in_sSearch, in_eCompareMethod)

        Loop Until FindFullWord = 0

    End If

End Function
```

I originally started doing a test for every character which could follow a word and would not be part of that word, but the code started getting very long. And, of course, I know absolutely nothing about Arabic. So I wondered whether there was a standard way of finding out the general "type" of a character, regardless of language. And as it happens, there was.

The GetStringTypeW() method is documented in the Win32 documentation, and essentially can retrieve information about all the characters in a string. In my case, I am only looking at the character which follows the search word in a piece of text. The variable `iCharType` which returns the value from the string is a bitfield, and contains a number of values OR'ed together. I am using the AND operator to isolate just the values I am interested in.